# Is there anyway to control the visibility of drag shadow in Android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Currently I'm working with tablet Android development. I want to drag a view from fragment A to fragment B, but the dragshadow will move from the destination to original position for the first time. Is there anyway to control the visibility of drag shadow in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable drag shadow using following property in your View Pager.

android:overScrollMode="never"

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Zealous System. But it is not my problem. I'm working with drag/drop: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop. And I want to hide the drag shadow when ACTION_DRAG_ENDED fired.